# Babylon JS - How can I make the transparent background

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I have an online project running with Babylon JS where I need to remove the gray and white background (which Babylon JS has by default), and leave the canvas completely transparent.

I need to see what's behind the canvas, and I can not ...

:(

How is it done, editing the .js or directly from my own html code?

Visit my project [here](https://vercomo.es/test/demo-babylon.html)

And the .js [here](https://vercomo.es/test/js/visor-2-master.js)

Thanks!

Comment: Please include relevant information in your question. Do not link to external resources. See [ask].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hello you should just be able to call:

```
scene.autoClear = false
```

Other option:

```
scene.clearColor = new BABYLON.Color4(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This is the solution I found. Thank! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.